# Do i need a Serializable Class to use in webflux webclient?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

**Request Class**

```
public class Request{
   String name;
   int age;
}
```

**Response Class**

```
public class Response{
   boolean status
   int id;
}
```

**Webclient Method:**

```
Response responseObj = webClient.post().
        .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authorisation)
        .bodyValue(requestObj)
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .retrieve().bodyToMono(Response.class)
        .block();
```

The above webclient method makes an api call and gets the output and converts into an java object. Everything works fine.

My Question is,
Eventhough it works, do i need to implement serializable interface for my POJO Classes?
Whats the best practice?
`public class Request implements Serializable`

Answer (score 2):

No, you don't need to implement `Serializable` because you are using JSON as the format of the data to be sent over the network.

You would need to implement `Serializable` if you would like to send your data as a byte stream instead of as JSON but this is not the case when you are calling what it seems to me to be a REST API.

Comment: @YUVAPRASATH, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.